# Class Method Can't Use Private Property of Same Class?

Tags: vba, excel

What am I misunderstanding about Private Properties in VBA classes? As a novice, I expected Private Properties to be accessible to other methods within the same class (module), but instead I get "Method or data member not found" when trying to compile.

---

**Breaks as Private Property Let lngMarketID**

Here's what I have in my standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Model As classModel

Set Model = New classModel
Model.Setup
```

with this class module named classModel:

```
Option Explicit

Private plngMarketID As Long


'plngMarketID Properties
Public Property Get lngMarketID() As Long
    lngMarketID = plngMarketID
End Property
Private Property Let lngMarketID(ByVal lngMarketID As Long)
    plngMarketID = lngMarketID
End Property


Public Sub Setup()

    SetuplngMarketID

End Sub

Private Sub SetuplngMarketID()

    Model.lngMarketID = CLng(DefaultLogicOptions.textboxMarketID.Value)

End Sub
```

---

**Works as Public Property Let lngMarketID**

The "Method or data member not found" highlights the `.lngMarketID` of the line in `SetuplngMarketID`. This compiles fine when I change `Private Property Let lngMarketID` to `Public Property Let lngMarketID`.

Comment: The code above is a basic programming error, but a more frequent error leading to the same error "not found" is the use of **`me`** in the class to access a **private** member -> see explanation and solution in [Why can't the VBA Me keyword access private procedures in its own module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895633/why-cant-the-vba-me-keyword-access-private-procedures-in-its-own-module) (whatever it's a private procedure, function, property, event, when it's used with `Me`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the "Model" in that line.  Model is a global variable pointing to some specific instance of your class.  From that object, only the public things are visible.

You want to refer to that from "inside" an arbitrary instance of your class, so just drop the Model prefix:

```
Private Sub SetuplngMarketID()

    lngMarketID = CLng(DefaultLogicOptions.textboxMarketID.Value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling "**Model.lngMarketId**", Model is the name of your variable of classModel object that isn't visible in the object it self.

you have to use "**lngMarketId = Clng(something)**"